# Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server : HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to enter into hive client , but keep getting the below error:

```
16/12/21 10:32:13 [main]: WARN hive.metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:266)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3000)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3019)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:484)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:680)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:624)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 33 more
16/12/21 10:32:13 [main]: INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://test.hadoop.cloud.abc.com:9083
```

I tried restarting metastore service and that shows:

MetaException(message:Hive Schema version 1.2.1000 does not match metastore's schema version 1.2.0 Metastore is not upgraded or corrupt)

Using hadoop 2.4 .
Anyhelp will be appreciated

Comment: Did you try to "upgrade" the Hive JARs without running the Metastore upgrade utility?? Cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool

Comment: No. I just did hadoop upgrade through Ambari , the upgrade failed towards the end . Making hive with the above error.

Comment: Failed upgrade => that's a major information.  WHY DIDN'T YOU MENTION IT IN THE FIRST PLACE?

Comment: So, did you try to run the Metastore upgrade utility, cf. my link above, to complete the upgrade and solve your version mismatch?